# IllegalArgumentException PID: 3701

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

LogCat:

```
Process: com.musicapp.android.musicapp, PID: 3701
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
      
        atcom.musicapp.android.musicapp.MusicCustomAdapter.getSongArt(MusicCustomAdapter.java:71)
```

Hiiii everyone, help me solve this please???? Thank you!

code:

```
  69  private byte[] getSongArt(String uri){
  70      MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
  7`     mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(uri);
        byte[] art = mediaMetadataRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        return art;
}
```

value of the uri:

```
byte[] image = getSongArt(newSong_list.get(position).getPath());
if (image != null){
    Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(image)
            .into(holder.SongCover);

}
```

path:

```
 newSong.path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
```

Comment: What is the value of `uri`?

Comment: I update it! Please take another look.

Comment: Ok.  And are you happy that `newSong_list.get(position).getPath()` is working as expected?

Comment: yes, I think it is.

Comment: I updated, the path is there.

Comment: although it is telling me that "DATA" is not deprecated.